# Is it possible to remove a top level Div in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a header for my website. With the use of Javascript the header dynamically builds html elements on the page.

However the header is responsive and if the screen size changes from desktop to mobile then I want to destroy the desktop instance of the header to rebuild the mobile one.

The problem is I can't figure out how to remove a div from a page that does not have a parent other than the body.

I know any child div can be deleted with [.removeChild](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_removechild.asp), but what if the div has no parent?

I tried putting the document in the place of a parent div like so:

```
document.removeChild(item-to-be-removed);
```

but I get a console error saying: "Node not found".

Any ideas?

Comment: get the the child of that div then use `.unwrap()`

Comment: @guradio Is .unwrap a jquery call? I can't find any documentation on it for pure java script.

Comment: Isn't body a parent of a div?

Comment: Use media query in css and just make `display:none` in mobile device width

Comment: @invisal  Oh yeah that worked! Perfect thank you, by calling document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].removeChild(div) it found the node. Not sure why that didn't cross my mind.

Comment: or you can do document.body.removeChild(div);

Comment: Since you are not going for responsive, you could always redirect to the mobile version of your site

Comment: Destroying the destkop header instance to rebuild it as mobile doesn't sound like a very efficient strategy, just saying ;-)

Comment: can't you add id or class attribute to child div?

Comment: @Arsylum Yeah you are probably right, this is my first time working on a project as a module so I guess I wanted to keep it as clean as possible, and the desktop version/mobile version are very different from eachother. They both have the same functionality, but it takes different layouts all together to build them. So I guess I thought it was the easiest thing to do to prevent memory leaks ect.... How would situations like this normally be handled?

Comment: as @ricky pointed out `display: none;` is your friend, it doen't just make elements invisible but also saves the ressources of rendering them on page. Reading into media queries might be a good idea ;-)
But if you really are going for totally differing layouts it's also worth considering to create two completely separate pages. It very much depends on your stack of frameworks and libraries - to me it looks like you are getting familiar with vanilla web standards, which is certainly a good foundation to have!

Answer (score 0):

This was answered by invisal in the comments. Instead of trying to call on the document as the parent of the node I wanted to delete. I should have called on the body like so:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].removeChild(item-to-delete);
```

That worked perfectly! Thank you for everyones help, and to those who asked why I wanted to delete the div and not just hide it with css, I'm doing it this way to help memory management and help me keep track of what the code is doing in my mind.

If I look at the mobile header in the inspector and I see bits of the desktop header leftover but just hidden it would interfere with my train of thought. Thank you for your help!

As pointed out, a easier to read option would be to call:

```
document.body.removeChild(item-to-delete);
```